# extracting a query result in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

Hello everyone will see I have the following query

```
$query = $this->PreguntasAlternativas->find();
$query->select(['id_alternativa' => $query->func()->max('id_alternativa')
        ])->where(['id_pregunta' => $idquestion]);
```

This returns me such an arrangement

```
query(array) 
 0(object)
  id_alternativa(null)
```

and what I want is to get the value returned me to then do a validation, not how to retrieve the value returned by the query me to do something like

```
if($query == null){
    $result = 1;
}else{
    $result = +1;
}
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my fues solution this, change the structure of my query

```
$query = $this->PreguntasAlternativas->find('all', ['conditions' =>       ['id_pregunta' => $idquestion]]);
    $result = $query->max('id_alternativa');
    if(!$result['id_alternativa']){
        $result['id_alternativa'] = 1;
    } else {
        $result['id_alternativa'] += 1;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Queries are lazily executed](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#how-are-queries-lazily-evaluated), and as such your query will be a `Cake\ORM\Query` object. You will need to execute the query in order to be able to process the results.

If you add `->toArray()` to your query, this will cause it to be executed and converted to an array. This will allow you to work with the results.